# ¿Cómo saber si el índice de un arreglo se repite varias veces en otro arreglo?

Tags: c#, array

Como saber si el indice se repite en alguno de los demas indices de el segundo arreglo, con esto quiero indicar que mientras mis tres arreglos sean únicos se debe de realizar mi acción.

Código actual:

```
registroA[contador]=AduanaOriginal[1];
registroP[contador] = PatenteOriginal[1];
registroPe[contador] = PedimentoOriginal[1];

if (registroA.Contains(AduanaOriginal[1]) && registroP.Contains(PatenteOriginal[1]) && registroPe.Contains(PedimentoOriginal[1]))
{

}
```

En ese código de arriba me indica si el índice de mi arreglo se encuentra en alguno de los índices de mi segundo arreglo, pero ahora me gustaría saber cómo puedo indicar que si el índice de mi arreglo existe en el arreglo con todos los índices, entonces se salte el resto del método y se salga.

Comment: ¿Deseas que los elementos de tus tres conjuntos A, P y Pe sean completamente diferentes si?

Comment: @Dan miranda si lo que quisiera es que entre ellos A con A, P con P y Pe con Pe sean diferentes y si llega haber un registro con A,P y Pe iguales entonces retorne ya que no es posible o no es permitible.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver el problema sera mejor plantearlo como conjuntos.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] X = new string[] {"A","B","C","D"};
        string[] Y = new string[] {"E","F","G","H"};
        string[] Z = new string[] {"E","F","G","A"};

        // Imprime 0
        Console.WriteLine(X.Intersect(Y).Count());
        // Imprime 1
        Console.WriteLine(X.Intersect(Z).Count());
        // Imprime False
        Console.WriteLine (X.Intersect(Y).Count() == 0 && X.Intersect(Z).Count() == 0);
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo estoy creando tres conjuntos y como se puede ver el elemento **A** se repite en el conjunto **X** y **Z**.

Para detectar esa repetición utilizamos el método **Intersect** de **Linq** que nos permite comparar dos *collecciones* y regresa los elementos que se repiten.

Sabiendo eso cuando revisamos la interseccion entre **X** y **Y** obtenemos una coleccion con **0** elementos por que no existe interseccion (repeticion).

Cuando comparamos **X** con **Z** existe una interseccion en **A**, por lo que regresa una coleccion de **1** elemento el cual es **A**

Utilizando esta logica de conjuntos puedes redefinir tus condiciones usando **Intersect**.

Comment: me sale el siguiente error cuando lo pongo dentro de un if "String no contiene una definicion para intersect"

Comment: Debe ser un String[] para que funcione el intersect. Debe ser comparacion entre arreglos.

Comment: ¿Deseas contar cuantas veces se repite?

Comment: no solo que si cuenta una interseccion o mas pues haga una accion diferentes

Comment: Ok, re lei tu pregunta, puedes romper el ciclo con break o return

Comment: hablando de eso si mi metodo es void no puede contener returns y el break no se aplica en sentencias if's como romperias la sentencia if?

Comment: Si puedes usar return en un void, solo escribes return;, el break lo comente por que crei que tu if estaba dentro de un for.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la muy buena respuesta de Dan Miranda.

... y un simple if?

```
if (X.Intersect(Y).Count() + X.Intersect(Z).Count() + Y.Intersect(Z).Count())>0 {
    Console.WriteLine("Hay elementos repetido");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No hay elementos repetidos");
}
```